# Get each button or anchor attributes as json string on click event javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all the attribute values as json string on each button and anchor element on a click event.

Like this.

```
<a href="test.html" div="mydiv" class="myclass" layer="mylayer"></a>
<button type="button" name="button" value="btnValue" id="btn"></button>

    {
        "attributes": {
             "href": "test.html",
             "div": "mydiv",
             "class": "myclass",
             "layer": "mylayer"
        }
    }

{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "button",
        "name": "button",
        "value": "btnValue",
        "id": "btn"
    }
}
```

This is my code js code

```
var attr = document.querySelectorAll('button, a');
for (var i = 0;i < attr.length;i++){
    attr[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log(attr);
      });
}
```

Can anyone help me with this how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56467370/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]. You also need to preventDefault on the link

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('button, a');
elements.forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var attrs = {attributes:{}};
    for(var i=0; i<e.currentTarget.attributes.length; i++) {
      attrs.attributes[e.currentTarget.attributes[i].name] = e.currentTarget.attributes[i].value;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(attrs));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. This can be trigger on click event on each element?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to the question. I edited my answer so it should be what you were looking for now.

Answer (score 0):

So this was pretty hacky but if you're looking to have an object like you've mentioned with each attribute and value, this works: https://jsfiddle.net/brydom/vkmxhj6o/3/

```
<a href="test.html" div="mydiv" class="myclass" layer="mylayer">Hi</a>
<button type="button" name="button" value="btnValue" id="btn">Hi again</button>
```

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('a,button');

for (let item of items) {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let attribute_object = {};

    for (let attribute_key in event.target.attributes) {
      const key = parseInt(attribute_key);

      if (key >= 0) {
        const attribute = event.target.attributes[key];
        attribute_object[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
      }
    }

    console.log(attribute_object);
  })
}
```

There *might* be a better way to do what you're trying to do if you can provide some context on why you need all of the attributes as well :)